# from sqlite3 BLOB (x,y data) to numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sqlite

I stored (x,y) data into a sqlite3 database, where they appear as 'BLOB'. E.g. the first BLOB has a size of 5653.

For reading this first BLOB I use:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_db)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT spectrum FROM spectra WHERE rowid=1')
sample_xy_blob = cur.fetchone()[0]
print(sample_xy_blob)
print(type(sample_xy_blob))

sample_xy_np = np.loadtxt( sample_xy_blob)
print(sample_xy_np)
print(type(sample_xy_np))
db.close()
```

The print outputs look the following:

```
>>> b'94.075\t.1\r\n95.057\t.4\r\n96.050\t2.8\r\n97.034\t3.8\r\n97.094\t.3\r\n97.143\t.1\r\n98.040\t.2\r\n98.066\t.4\r\n99.050\t6.0\r\n99.188\t.1\r\n100.053\t.2\r\n100.078\t.2\r\n101.065\t.6\r\n102.061\t.2\r\n103.049\t1.6\r\n103.143\t.1\r\n104.067\t.1\r\n104.106\t.2\r\n106.089\t.2\r\n109.0...
<class 'bytes'>
[ 57.  52.  46. ...,  10.  13.  10.]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> print(sample_xy_np.shape)
(5653,)
```

How do I get a 2D (x,y) numpy array out of this?

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the decoding of the BLOB, which has to be converted into a string, and then into a numerical array. This can be done by:

```
spec_xy_np = np.fromstring(spec_xy_blob,  sep = '\t')
spec_xy_np = np.reshape(spec_xy_np, (-1, 2))
```

The first command generates a numerical 1D array. The separator option sep = '\t' is important to avoid errors because of empty lines. The second line changes the 1D array to a 2D (x,y) array, without needing the number of entries.